# how to change background video according to condition in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

guys I am have started learning html,css,and java script but i came across a problem that I am unable to solve I have tried many solutions but nothing is working , your help will be appreciated
html:

```js
var l;
function timer(){
    var d = new Date();
    var time_hour = d.getHours();
    var time_min = d.getMinutes();
    var time_sec = d.getSeconds();
    l = time_hour;
    document.querySelector("#hour").innerHTML = time_hour + ":";
    document.querySelector("#min").innerHTML = time_min + ":";
    document.querySelector("#sec").innerHTML = time_sec ;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){ timer() }, 500);
    }
function checking(){
    if (l>=0){
            document.querySelector(".video").setAttribute("src","videos/5.mp4");
    }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Clock</title>
</head>
<body onload="timer(); checking()" > 
    <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" >
        <source src="" type="video/mp4" class="video" >
      </video>
    <div class="cont">
        <h2 class="made-by">Made By Muaaz Bin Sarfraz</h2>
    </div>
       <ul class="entry">
           <li id="hour"></li>
           <li id="min"></li>
           <li id="sec"></li>
       </ul>
       
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is wrong with that? Any error message?

Comment: yeah the problem was solved i was not including the src tag inside video tag , that was causing the problem

Comment: Then, please, add an answer for newcomers.

Comment: yeah i  have posted mate, i am kinda new in to programming world so i am learning the use of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

yeah my problem is solved, i was adding the src attribute in source tag instead of video tag that was causing problem`

```html
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo"  >
        <source type="video/mp4" class="video"  >
      </video>
```

```js
javascript:

    var l;
function timer(){
    var d = new Date();
    var time_hour = d.getHours();
    var time_min = d.getMinutes();
    var time_sec = d.getSeconds();
    l = time_hour;
    document.querySelector("#hour").innerHTML = time_hour + ":";
    document.querySelector("#min").innerHTML = time_min + ":";
    document.querySelector("#sec").innerHTML = time_sec ;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){ timer() }, 500);
    }
function checking(){
    if ((l>=0)&&(l<=5)){
        document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/5.mp4");
    }
    else if((l>=6)&&(l<=9)){
        document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/1.mp4");
    }
    else if((l>=9)&&(l<=12)){
        document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/2.mp4");
    }
    else if((l>=13)&&(l<=17)){
        document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/3.mp4");
    }
    else if((l>=18)&&(l<=20)){
        document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/4.mp4");
    }
  else if((l>=21)&&(l<=23)){
    document.querySelector("#myVideo").setAttribute("src","videos/5.mp4");
}
}
```